# What's the default value for Git `rebase.instructionFormat` config variable?

Tags: git, git-config, git-interactive-rebase

Git 2.6 added the [`rebase.instructionFormat` config variable](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt-rebaseinstructionFormat) for configuring the format of the interactive rebase instruction lines. As per the documentation, the different [formatting options](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) one can choose come from `git log`. But the documentation does not state, that if one were to start customizing this config, what is the default value for that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's currently `%s`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4af7188bc97f70277d0f10d56d5373022b1fa385/sequencer.c#L5661) (=commit subject). Hard to say why it's not documented.

Answer (score 0):

> Hard to say why it's not documented.

Because it's never been:

> An editor will be fired up with all the commits in your current branch (ignoring merge commits), which come after the given commit. You can reorder the commits in this list to your heart’s content, and you can remove them. **The list looks more or less like this**:
>
> ```
> pick deadbee The oneline of this commit
> pick fa1afe1 The oneline of the next commit
> ...
> ```
>
> The oneline descriptions are purely for your pleasure; git rebase will not look at them but at the commit names ("deadbee" and "fa1afe1" in this example), so do not delete or edit the names.

Emphasis mine. That was the only documentation of the interactive rebase file format I could find.